# Encoding for embedding python in C++

Tags: python, c++, python-embedding

I'm trying to embed a python code in C++ and it compiles successfully but when I try to run my code, I get the following error.

```
File "./cppPython", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x88' in file ./cppPython on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

These are my C++ and Python codes.

> CPP code

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[0],"r");
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();

  PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags(fp,argv[0],0,NULL);

  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

> Python code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print "hello"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv[0]` gives the C++ executable name. For eg. If you named the C++ executable as `abc` and executed as:

`./abc pythonFileName.py`

Then the `argv` array will have `argv[0]` as `./abc` and `argv[1]` as `pythonFileName.py`.

So, please use the index 1.

Answer (score 1):

You're running the executable as Python code, which it is not. Verify the arguments to `fopen()` and `PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags()`.

Comment: Hello Ignacio. Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain your answer a bit? I couldn't understand what you said.

Comment: Do you understand what `argv` is?

Comment: This is the way I'm running my cpp code `./cppPython cppPython.py`. Basically, argv is the array containing the arguments that I pass to my c++ code.

Comment: "argv is the array containing the arguments that I pass to my c++ code" Incorrect. It is all words parsed from the command line, not just the arguments.

Comment: Ohh, I got it. Thanks Ignacio. Now, I call fopen like `fopen(argv[1],"r")` and my code works as it should. Thanks again.